# How to capitalize first letter in bash?

Tags: bash

```sh
editAppsDotPy() {
    echo 'from django.apps import AppConfig' >> apps.py
    echo >> apps.py
    echo >> apps.py
    echo "class ${APP_NAME}Config(AppConfig):" >> apps.py
    echo "    name = '${APP_NAME}'" >> apps.py
}
```

How would you capitalize the variable in the 5th line?
I was trying to do it with `${APP_NAME^}` but it returns me an error.

Comment: Works fine for me. What error?

Comment: @Thomas `manage.sh: line 29: ${APP_NAME^}: bad substitution`

Comment: Which version of `bash` do you have and what is the she-bang which is on the first line of your script?

Comment: Be sure the script is run with Bash and not some other Shell. This case changing expansion is a Bash specific feature.

Comment: @kvantour `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)` and `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @LéaGris I'm not sure it's correct version, so there's another `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)` from `bash --version`, the previous one was from `zsh --version`

Comment: `${foo^}` is invalid `zsh` syntax, yes.

Comment: @Shawn good to know. I need a universal solution for every type.

Comment: And it was added to `bash` in 4.0.

Comment: `declare -c APP_NAME="foo"; echo "$APP_NAME"`

Comment: @Cyrus i don't get it. I'm using bash for two days and only for particular problem ;p

Comment: @Cyrus Nice one, I didn't know this one. Where did you find it? It is not documented; neither in `help declare` nor in [bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).

Comment: @Socowi: yes, it's not documented. I found it in bash's source code.

Comment: @Socowi you can find it here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html

Comment: Continued support for `$[...]` notwithstanding, I would hesitate to use undocumented features.

Answer (score 4):

Your function rewritten to work with more various shells:

`script.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

capitalize()
{
  printf '%s' "$1" | head -c 1 | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
  printf '%s' "$1" | tail -c '+2'
}

editAppsDotPy()
{
  cat >> 'app.py' <<EOF
from django.apps import AppConfig

class $(capitalize "$APP_NAME")Config(AppConfig):
    name = '$APP_NAME'
EOF
}

APP_NAME='foo'

editAppsDotPy
```

Demoing:

```sh
sh script.sh
cat app.py
```

Output:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class FooConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'foo'
```

Comment: it capitalizes and writes only the first letter of the variable

Comment: Um, isn't that what you asked for? After all, the title of your question is *`How to capitalize first letter in bash?`*. You can (and should!) change the title by clicking `edit` at the bottom left of your question.

Comment: @Socowi instead of FooConfig it returns FConfig.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. `APP_NAME=foo editAppsDotPy; cat app.py` prints `fooConfig(...` (unchanged because this is the 4th line) and `name = 'Foo'` (correctly capitalized in the 5th line).

Comment: your code returns it https://pastebin.com/4Kgke1Su

Comment: @Sevy modified the `capitalize` function to use `cat` for the reminder of the string. Can you try again with this version?

Comment: @Sevy That is really strange. I get the correct output in dash 0.5.10.2 and bash 4.4.12, 4.4.20, and 5.0.3 on my system and [these](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) [two](https://repl.it/repls/MammothBumpyPlans#main.sh) online IDEs. Are you sure you correctly copied the script posted in this answer? It is suspicious that the 4th line (which just printed the unmodified variable `$APP_NAME` in the first version of this answer) returned something different than assigned.

Comment: still the same problem.

Comment: @Socowi yes. I'm pretty sure that I copied everything properly. I did it even for few times.

Comment: changing shebang, indentation etc. also does nothing.

Comment: @Sevy Look like MacOS's `head` command is terminating the input stream. So I wrote it differently by re-injecting the string separately for the remaining unchanged characters. Please try again with this latest version.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `head` will read *only* as much data as it needs in order to write its requested output.

Comment: @LéaGris finally it works. thank you guys.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that *tr* is in your path, the more common parameter substitutions can help you too.
Your fifth line could look like the following:

```
echo "class `tr [:lower:] [:upper:] <<<${APP_NAME:0:1}`${APP_NAME:1}Config(AppConfig):" >> apps.py
```

I also tested this in zsh 5.8.

Comment: imo the best solution but know my whole code is treated as a string

Comment: @Sevy good solution but uses Bash's or Zsh's specific index expansion feature, that does not exist in Ksh or purely POSIX shells.

Comment: @LéaGris on top of that, zsh is not POSIX compliant.

Comment: As well as `<<<"here string"` redirection syntax is non-portable feature, not available with POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of `bash` is too old to support that extension (Like the OS X version), or you're using a shell like `zsh` that doesn't support it at all, you have to turn to something else. Personally, I like `perl` (Which I *think* OS X comes with):

```
$ perl -ne 'print ucfirst' <<<"foobar"
Foobar
```

or for something in the middle of a longer string:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo "foo='$(perl -ne 'print ucfirst' <<<"$foo")'"
foo='Bar'
```

which works in `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: Could you explain me, how does it work with particular situtation?

Comment: @Sevy What part? The perl just titlecases its input. Everything else is just basic shell command substitution and herestrings.

Comment: I don't know how should it look in my situation.